# Application duplicating desktop and start menu icons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce, desktop-application

I've looked at this all over Google and Stack Overflow, and it looks like nobody is having the same issue as me, or they know enough about click once to solve it.

For some background I'm currently using Visual Studio Community 2015 and have created a WPF click once application written in C#. The application is stored on a network drive location and it checks for updates before opening each time.

It all seems to be working well, apart from when it updates. It asks the user to update as expected, and updates like it should, but once the user accepts, it duplicates the desktop and start menu icons, so I get 'My Application-1', instead of overwriting the icon (I've changed the icon a few times due to logo changes) or just leaving it alone (when it's not changed).

Am I missing something in the publish settings, or am I doing something wrong? I really don't want user's with an extra icon each time my application updates. I have plans to make a number of updates over the next few weeks/months, and I ca see my users (it's an internal application) getting tired of deleting desktop icons. In fact, I don't think they even have access to delete the start menu icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're not changing anything that is part of the deployment identity, such as the executable or the URL -- this includes not changing the case of any of the strings. The problem you are having is because it doesn't recognize the upgrade as the same application you've already installed, except for the start menu items.

Comment: Thanks, this does look like the case, when I've rolled it out to everyone else it hasn't happened, so I must have changed it somewhere to make it think it was a different application. I'll make sure I don't change anything that doesn't need changing in future.

Comment: It's sneaky, and they don't warn you. I figured it out via trial & error -- in my case, it was the case of the URL, I changed it from lowercase to mixed case.

Comment: it happens to me when I copy the LNK file from one PC to another one. It couldn't be a problem related only to the fact the URL is written in another manner...

Comment: You should never copy the shortcut file from one PC to another. There are other things that are written to the registry when you install the app. Why do you need to do this, doesn't it create the shortcut when you install it?